# Get product Images with Prestashop webservice

Tags: php, web-services, api, prestashop

I am trying to get images for a product in Prestashop Webservice. Currently I've managed to get description, price, title etc. But when I try to get the images it only gives me the ID of the images, not the complete url. If I go to http://your-url.com/...cts/XproductidX I can with no problem get the images, but doing this through the webservice, is apparently a bit more complicated.

Here is my code so far:

```
$opt = array(
        'resource' => 'products',
        'display' => 'full',
        'limit' => 5,
    );
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);
    $resources = $xml->children()->children();

    foreach($resources as $product){
        if($product->id[0] == 286){

            $title = $product->meta_title->language;
            $description = $product->meta_description->language;
            $description_short = $product->description_short;
            $quantity = $product->quantity;
            $price = $product->price;
            $wholesale_price = $product->wholesale_price;

            $images = $product->associations->images;
            print_r($images);
        }
    }
```

With that print_r at the bottom, I am able to receive following:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [nodeType] => image
            [api] => images
        )

    [image] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 34
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 35
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 36
                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 37
                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 38
                )

            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 39
                )

            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 40
                )

        )

)
```

This gives me the ID of the images. Is there any way to get the full url, or at least get image url through an resource?
Perhaps I am doing this the wrong way? :-)

Regards, Simon

Comment: I know how to get images (binary), not url,  `api/images/products/[id_product]/[id_image]` or call `api/images/products/[id_product]/` to get all links. Also docs http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service . Hope it will help.

Comment: @simond did you resolve this? I need this also.

Answer (score -1):

You could just try to add

'display' => 'full' on your opt commands.

This should resolve the Ids and give you the full sub-objects.